# Convert Scala Set into Java (java.util.Set)?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, scala-collections, scala-2.8, scala-java-interop

I have a Set in Scala (I can choose any implementation as I am creating the Set. The Java library I am using is expecting a java.util.Set[String].

Is the following the correct way to do this in Scala (using scala.collection.jcl.HashSet#underlying):

```
import com.javalibrary.Animals

var classes = new scala.collection.jcl.HashSet[String]
classes += "Amphibian"
classes += "Reptile"
Animals.find(classes.underlying)
```

It seems to be working, but since I am very new to Scala I want to know if this is the preferred way (any other way I try I am getting a type-mismatch error):

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.jcl.HashSet[String]
 required: java.util.Set[_]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you were asking about Scala 2.8, Java collections interoperability is supplied by `scala.collection.JavaConversions`. In this case, you want JavaConversions.asSet(...) (there's one for each direction, Java -> Scala and Scala -> Java).

For Scala 2.7, each scala.collection.jcl class that wraps a Java collection has an `underlying` property which provides the wrapped Java collection instance.

Answer (score 10):

Since Scala 2.12.0 `scala.collection.JavaConversions` [is deprecated](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html):

> Therefore, this API has been deprecated and JavaConverters should be used instead. JavaConverters provides the same conversions, but through extension methods.

And since Scala 2.8.1 you can [use](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) `scala.collection.JavaConverters` for this purpose:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val javaSet = new java.util.HashSet[String]()
val scalaSet = javaSet.asScala
val javaSetAgain = scalaSet.asJava
```

Comment: And for 2.13 JavaConverters have been deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

Note that starting `Scala 2.13`, package [`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) replaces deprecated packages `scala.collection.JavaConverters/JavaConversions._`:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

// val scalaSet: Set[String] = Set("a", "b")
val javaSet = scalaSet.asJava
// javaSet: java.util.Set[String] = [a, b]
javaSet.asScala
// scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set(a, b)
```

Answer (score 5):

For 2.7.x I *highly* recommend using: http://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-javautils

Answer (score 4):

In Scala 2.12 it is possible to use : `scala.collection.JavaConverters.setAsJavaSet(scalaSetInstance)`

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for the way to do it from within Java code + this fits the bill