# Convert java.util.Set to scala.collection.Set

Tags: scala, set

How can I convert a java.util.Set[String] to a scala.collection.Set with a generic type in Scala 2.8.1?

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

var in : java.util.Set[String] = new java.util.HashSet[String]()

in.add("Oscar")
in.add("Hugo")

val out : scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(in.toArray : _*)
```

And this is the error message

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;  
found   : Array[java.lang.Object]
required: Array[_ <: String]   
val out : scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(javaset.toArray : _*)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29) called on a java `Set` will return an array of `Object`. Since you already imported `JavaConversions`, `asScalaSet` will implicitly convert your Java set to a mutable Scala set or use `toSet` to convert it to an immutable set.

See also [Convert Scala Set into Java (java.util.Set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233576/convert-scala-set-into-java-java-util-set)

Comment: I read them, but the function asSet doesn't work. With toSet is works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: FYI JavaConversions is deprecated as of Scala 2.12.0. Use JavaConverters.

Answer (score 26):

Use [JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) instead

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val out = in.asScala

out: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set(Hugo, Oscar)
```

Comment: Oddly, but this import statement fails:  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._  I use Scala version 2.8.1

Comment: JavaConverters is avaliable Since 2.8.1

Comment: this gives scala.collection.mutable.Set and I need scala.collection.immutable.Set

Answer (score 0):

That's an outdated answer. One needs to import

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.*
```

as shown in https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html

and then use `.asScala` or `.asJava` method based on the target collection type.