# Scala Map to Java HashMap

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

I have a Scala function `f(s1: String, s2: String): Map[String,String]`

I want to allow a colleague coding in Java to call a Java method I'm writing:

`HashMap<String, String> f(String s1, String s2)`

This calls my Scala function.  What I've found, on the Java side, is that Scala has returned a `scala.collection.immutable.Map`.

How do I make a Java HashMap out of it?  Or should I be doing something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Scala Set into Java (java.util.Set)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233576/convert-scala-set-into-java-java-util-set)

Comment: Although Set was mentioned in that question, in fact the same goes for most Scala -> Java collections.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$). Specifically the `mapAsJavaMap` method.

[Where the preferred usage is explained in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301947/what-is-the-difference-between-javaconverters-and-javaconversions-in-scala) Using imported `implicits` and `asJava`

Comment: Thanks, Justin.  That got me on the right path.  Over on the Scala side I did this: `val im = f(s1,s2); val mm = collections.mutable.Map(im:toSeq: _*); JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(mm)` and that resulted in a mutable map on the Java side (which I think is what Java was looking for, and my map was immutable).

Comment: Actually, you want `import JavaConverters._` and `m.asJava`. This is common wisdom and must have a duplicate question if someone could find it. The style guide is to use converters and explicitly ask for the conversion.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but I'm with som-snytt—this is essentially a link-only answer that suggests an unidiomatic use of a package that most Scala developers agree should be avoided.

Comment: @som-snytt Sorry, I was relying on the built-in documentation too much. Edited to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, som-snytt, I'll follow your suggestion going forward.